# Sample code or demo for Digital Goods for PayPal Express Checkout in HTML?

Tags: paypal, payment

The documentation for implementing PayPal Express Checkout in HTML is a little cryptic. In particular, we are interested in implementing the Digital Goods for Express Checkout experience in HTML.

Is it similar to the code for the HTML implementation of Website Payments Standard? The documentation for Payments Standard seems clearer to us, but perhaps we are looking in the wrong place. Is there a better resource to consult than this one: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG

Best of all, could anyone share sample code of an HTML implementation for the Digital Goods for Express Checkout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post on the PayPal developer blog with sample code:

<s>https://www.x.com/blogs/matt/2011/02/15/another-digital-goods-demo</s> (Link is dead)

It used to contain a working demo, but it was taken down for some reason.

Comment: To see the working demo, PM the blogger. PayPal forced him to take down the demo for bandwidth purposes, but he's able to share the demo URL privately. It's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of server side language to be completely secure with Express Checkout. Express Checkout is not intended to be used only with HTTP POST and GET requests because your API credentials are required, and that can be viewed in a POST/GET.

But Express checkout essentially has 3 API calls, Set, Get, Do.

The Digital Goods feature of Express Checkout works pretty much the same as the standard Express Checkout functionality, except you can use iframes and a 'mini-browser' version of checkout.